# How does a Django ModelForm query the database for a ForeignKey member in the corresponding Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models in models.py

```
class Inner(models.Manager):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Outer(models.Manager):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    inner = models.ForeignKey(Data)
```

I then have a `ModelForm` for `Outer`.

```
class OuterModelForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Outer
    fields = ['name', 'inner']
```

My question is what gets called by ModelForm when displaying the possible inner values in the drop-down in the generated form.

I have ruled out the following by overriding the `objects` with a custom `models.Manager`. (just by adding print in there and seeing what is called)

- `values`
- `get`
- `get_queryset`
- `all`
- `filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the responsibility of the form field, which will call its `queryset` attribute. By default, this is simply the related class's default manager; in your case, `Data.objects.all()`.

To change this, redefine the field with an explicit queryset:

```
class OuterModelForm(ModelForm):
    inner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Data.objects.filter(myparam='whatever'))
```

or, if you need it to depend on some other parameter, explicitly set that attribute within the `__init__` method:

```
class OuterModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        param = kwargs.pop('myparam', None)
        super(OuterModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['inner'].queryset = Data.objects.filter(myparam=param)
```